# How to detect array type in Template toolkit?

Tags: perl, types, template-toolkit

I need to detect some variable for accessory to array type in Template toolkit.
Are there best practices?

Comment: I don't understand. Can you give an example of what you're trying to achieve and possibly something you've tried which didn't work?

Comment: There is variable in TT template file: `[% var %]`. I need to detect type of this variable (array or not).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your data should be validated by the controller BEFORE it's passed to the template.  There should be no mystery what format your data is in.

That said, the most useful method to check this would just be testing the [`array`](http://www.template-toolkit.org/docs/manual/Variables.html#section_List_References)'s size:

```
[% IF var.size %]


[% END %]
```

Comment: If the array is empty then testing the size would result in a false negative.

Comment: What if the array has one element? It also returns 1.

Comment: Also, scalar.size will return 1 and hashref.size will return the number of key/value pairs.

Comment: With regards to the issues I outlined, they could be circumvented by overriding the scalar and hash size virtual methods to always return undef i.e. `$Template::Stash::SCALAR_OPS->{ size } = sub { undef }; $Template::Stash::HASH_OPS->{ size } = sub { undef };`, then test that the result of var.size is defined i.e. `[% IF var.size.defined; 'ARRAY'; END %]`.

Comment: @Chris, scalar.size and hashref.size — what do you mean?

Comment: @bibimij scalar and hashref are the names of psuedo variables that describe their datatypes. I used them to express my point i.e. `[% hashref = { }; hashref.size %]`. If you read my answer, your problem can be resolved by defining your own virtual method. I defined a general ref one, but you may prefer to define an is_array() one.

Comment: See my answer to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51539514/perl-template-alloy-and-template-toolkit-array-ref for a solution that actually works (not like this answer).

Answer (score 5):

It would be possible to define a custom virtual method which returns the ref type of the variable supplied. Rough example:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Template;
use Template::Stash;

$Template::Stash::SCALAR_OPS->{ ttref } = \&ttref;
$Template::Stash::LIST_OPS  ->{ ttref } = \&ttref;
$Template::Stash::HASH_OPS  ->{ ttref } = \&ttref;

my $t = Template->new( );

$t->process( \*DATA, { vars => [ 1, [ ], { } ] } );

sub ttref
{
    return ref $_[0];
}

__DATA__
[% FOREACH var IN vars -%]
ref type of [% var %] is [% var.ttref %]
[% END %]
```

Output:

```
ref type of 1 is 
ref type of ARRAY(0x9cfbd0) is ARRAY
ref type of HASH(0x9cfc00) is HASH
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this, Chris.  I still stand by my original assertion that the OP's question is likely a symptom that he's using templates in a way beyond their best practices.  The format of one's data should not be a mystery to the level that one needs to examine ref types, and if it is there is a flaw in the controller or model.  Nevertheless, thanks for sharing this advanced feature.  +1

Comment: I completely agree, in years of using template toolkit, I have never needed to detect the ref type internally.

Comment: best practice is one side, generally I assume yes, but on other side there are some more edge cases, which do not necessarily imply bad practice imho for which it can be used. Best practice now, does not have to be best practice 5 years later, so best practice is not actually always best practice. Although in majority guess 90% of cases it is, but it might depend on the case. Anyway I see/ realize I upvoted your solution above mainly, I mean it generally to indicate I do accept , not deny your solution. Eg. the need for workaround might stem from a small shortcoming of the platform used.