# Perl - Template Alloy and Template toolkit array ref

Tags: perl, template-toolkit

I using template alloy and Template toolkit, in TT I want to detect array reference like i do with perl:

```
for my $parents ( @{$value} ){

  if (ref($parents) ne 'ARRAY'){
    push @all_urls_names, $parents;
  }

}
```

This is my code in tt:

```
use warnings;
use v5.20; #strict is already set in the version

use Template;

my $t = Template->new(
    INCLUDE_PATH => ['.'],
);

my @menus = ( 

 ["parent",
   [qw(child1 child12 child13 child14) ]
 ],

 );

my $mvs = {# my variables
   menus => \@menus
};

$t->process("index.tt", $mvs, \my $out) || die $t->error;

sub {
   return [ 200, [], [ $out ] ];
}
```

In the index.tt:

```
[% FOR base = menus %]

 [% FOR parent = base %]

   [% IF ref.parent ne "ARRAY" %]
      <li>[% parent %] </li>
   [% END %]

 [% END %]

[% END %]
```

If I remove the `IF` statement, I get this:

parent
ARRAY(0x2539ad8)

I want to just get `parent`

I can fix just doing  [% FOR parent = base.0 %]

but I want to know a solution to get ref array in TT.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to detect array type in Template toolkit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23912898/how-to-detect-array-type-in-template-toolkit)

Answer (score 1):

This line is wrong in multiple ways:

```
[% IF ref.parent ne "ARRAY" %]
```

You try to dereference a (non-existing) variable `ref`.  Instead you wanted something like `parent.ref()` to invoke a VMethod `ref` on the variable `parent`.  But there is no such VMethod in Template Toolkit.

And there is also no operator `ne` in Template Toolkit.  It's `!=`.  You have to find out where syntax errors are logged and check that.

There is a hack though to find out whether a variable is a plain array reference.  You can try this code with your example Perl file:

```
[% stringified = '' _ menus %]
[% IF stringified.match('ARRAY\\(0x[0-9a-f]+\\)') %]
    array ref ([% stringified %])
[% ELSE %]
    not an array ref ([% stringified %])
[% END %]
```

Basically, this checks whether the variable `menus`, when coerced into a string, matches the default rendering of an array reference in Template Toolkit (and Perl).  It's a hack with a number of caveats but it works for practical purposes, when you know your input data.